# How can i set ios project target from 9.2 to 9.3?

Tags: ios, xcode, target

I am trying to upload my iOS app to app store but I was rejected.
How can I set iOS project target from 9.2 to 9.3? 
Is there anybody help me about this subject?

[image]

Comment: The rejection reason was only because of targeting 9.2?!

Comment: For the reason they says "We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad running iOS 9.3.1 on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks.",

And i think my xcode target sdk is 9.2. And if can i change it to 9.3 may be i can solve this problem.

Comment: So it's not about targeting, try to find and solve the bugs.

Comment: İ dont know how to find bugs . my simulators version is 9.2 how can upgrade them to 9.3 ? if dont i have 9.3 target device i cant find bugs

Comment: @kadari what was the reason for rejection ? can u post here?

Comment: i was posted it but i will pos again.


We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad running iOS 9.3.1 on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comment you need to update your xcode.

1. **If you have installed Xcode using App Store then update this way**

go to App Store --> click on Updates tab on right top bar.

[image]

2. **If you have installed Xcode using DMG file downloaded then update this way**

[Click here to download Xcode 9.3 DMG](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.3/Xcode_7.3.dmg)

you may need to login with apple account to get start downlaod

---

once you have Updated Xcode 7.3.x then you can update target sdk

open project -> Settings --> General --> Deployment info

[image]

> Just go for developer testing throughout the app with Wi-Fi and
>   cellular networks as Apple engineers suggested for possible bugs on iPad/iPhone with updated ios 9.3.x

If everything goes fine lets prepare you Build with distribution certificate and upload to iTunesConnect to publish updated build.

Note : You can check any time your Xcode version installed

Just go to Xcode Menu --> About

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks but i can not see 9.3 in my xcode. my xcode version is 7.2 how can i update xcode ?

https://s23.postimg.org/qgk1023kr/hata1.png

Comment: @Kadri I have added instructions for updating xcode IDE 9.3

Comment: i dont have any update for xcode or another thing :/ {https://s9.postimg.org/jvdbtn8n3/hata2.png}

Comment: oh thanks i will try it. At last thing how can i add image to comment. My images are like an url but yours are looking good ?

Comment: Sure i have added image to your question, [How to add image in post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83096/how-to-place-an-image-in-a-stack-overflow-question)

Comment: thank you i solve this and uploaded my app to apple app store :)

Comment: @Kadri I am glad that its helps you, [please accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so it will help someone in future also.

Answer (score -1):

update to Xcode 7.3+, and download 9.3 Simulator
[image]